# Getting a syntax error in creating a new policy using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was tried to run following command to create a new policy.

```
$ aws iam create-policy --policy-name my-policy --policy-document file://ex-policy.json
```

But I've gotten following error.

> An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.

The policy.json is in my current directory and it looks like this.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["sns:Publish"],
      "Resource": ["*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is my issue?

Answer (score 2):

In this policy, `"Version": "2012-10-17T00:00:00.000Z",` is incorrect. It should be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["sns:Publish"],
      "Resource": ["*"]
    }
  ]
}
```